# angularjs: example from docs.civicrm.org does not work

Tags: drupal

I did the exact steps listed in `https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/angular/quickstart/` on my drupal7-civicrm4.6 installation.
Calling the url `my_site.com/?q=civicrm/a/#/about/me` displays nothing.

Any ideas what the problem could be? It should not be about caching, as I executed `drush cc all` and cleared the cache from the CiviCRM GUI.

Comment: Basic question, but have you enabled the new extension? I just don't see any steps for it in the gude

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments you should be sure to enable your extensions such as with `cv ext:enable <extension name>`

Check what warnings you're getting in the console. I was getting warnings about the injector but after clearing the cache (`drush cc civicrm`) and setting the right file permissions on the files in my extension these went away and I could view the page.

I was still getting errors about a missing CSS file, but I think this is a bug where these angular modules don't respect the variable extensions directory (my extensions are separate from the application files)